# How can I prevent focus from moving to the next field if a given EditText is empty?

Tags: java, android

I add five EditText controls dynamically, and I want to check that they are filled in before moving to the next step. Here's what I have so far:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_form)

    EditText nameedit = new EditText(this);
    nameedit.setHint("First name");
    blur.addView(nameedit);
    nameedit.setWidth(32);
    nameedit.setEms(50);
    MarginLayoutParams params3 = (MarginLayoutParams) nameedit.getLayoutParams();
    params3.leftMargin = 16; params3.topMargin = 125;
    nameedit.setLayoutParams(params3);
    Typeface font33=Typeface.SERIF;
    nameedit.setTypeface(font33);
    nameedit.setMaxLines(1);
    nameedit.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
    nameedit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: maybe I miss understand your questions but what the problem with nameedit.getText().toString().isEmpty()

Comment: If you're gonna touch the body of a question like this, @1000000000, then fix *everything* - put a description of the problem at the top, make sure the grammar and capitalization are correct, etc. Don't waste folks' time reviewing half-hearted edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to "Next step" might be done through a button click right? If so, just, use

`nameedit.getText().toString().length()` to get the length of input. Check if its `zero` or not. Do the same stuff for other 4 `EditText`.

Based on the validation proceed to next step.

Change your `Reg_btn.setOnClickListener(this);` to following:

```
Reg_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if(nameedit.getText().toString().length()>0){// also use && to validate other 4 edittext views
                                   //do your stuff here
                            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: @user2610135 How are you checking if the edit text is empty or not? Update the question with code of button click listener.

Comment: like this
nameedit.getText().toString().length();

  


Code of button:
  Button Reg_btn = new Button (this);
  Reg_btn.setText("REGISTER");
  Reg_btn.setId(60);
  Reg_btn.setTextSize(20);
  Reg_btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
  Reg_btn.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
  Reg_btn.setLayoutParams(params5);
  Reg_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: ooo waoo cool it worked:-) 
but now bcz i remove my intent code from Onclick view......when i pressed button it will not go to next activity. where i put my intent code now

Comment: put the intent code in `// do your stuff` area. Glad it worked, please accept the answer if its done. :)

Comment: i put && but i did not apply on all 5 field
   if((pass_edit.getText().toString().length()>0)&&nameedit.getText().toString().length()>0) and so on........